# Yowsup connection to whatsapp raise Disconnected because close exception

Tags: python, whatsapp, yowsup

I have installed the yowsub library (the latest version ) on my device ( Ubuntu 12.04 )

also I have obtained the request code by running this command

```
$ ./yowsup-cli --requestcode sms --config yowsup-cli.config
```

and then I registered it successfully using this command

```
$ ./yowsup-cli --register {MY-CODE} --config yowsup-cli.config
```

after that I entered the returned password in the configuration file.

but when I try to send messages by this command

```
$ ./yowsup-cli --send {Destination phone with it's country code} "Test message" --wait --config yowsup-cli.config
```

I have the following exception

```
Disconnected because close
```

I tried more than solution related to this issue but the result was the same exception.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by downloading a new fork of the yowsube library from this link

http://mandroslabs.com/mandrosian/

and it's now working good.